# Undefined Index $_POST Error in Ajax, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Getting Undefined Index postBody Error in Ajax
I don't know how to fix this.
 
I have already checked many posts but that didn't help.

---

HTML CODE in index.php:

```
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="postBody" type="text" id="postBody" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="postButton" id="postButton" value="POST" class="cg nq w-50">
</form>
```

Here is Ajax Code in my index.php at the end after jquery cdn.

```
$("#postButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = $("#postBody").val();
    var dataString = 'postBody='+body;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:dataString,
        url:'submitPost.php',
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

---

And this is submitPost.php Code.

```
include("config.php");
global $con;
$body = $_POST['postBody'];
$date_added = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$body','$date_added')");

if($query == 1){
   echo "Post Submitted";
else{
   echo "Error";
}
```

This code actually Return Post Submitted in alert and Insert the $date_added and but not $body.
    **Error: undefined Index postBody in postSubmit.php on 3.**

Comment: Try to `console.log(body);` after `var body = $("#postBody").val();` ? Also in php `var_dump($body)` after `$body = $_POST['postBody'];`

Comment: Try - `data: $('form').serialize(),` . You are not passing the data properly.

Comment: I'm not a jQuery user but shouldn't the POST data be an array instead of a string ?  Does not look logical to me.

Comment: Another try: `var dataString =  { postBody : body };`  (of course it then won't be `dataString` but that's just the name) - jquery will serialise the object correctly.

Comment: Yes.. Should be a data object.

Comment: Or: `url:'submitPost.php?dataString` and remove `data:dataString`

Comment: Change `data:dataString,` to `data: { postBody: body },`

Comment: ok let me try :)

Comment: @AymDev it should be an object rather than a string (not an 'array' as such).

Comment: @freedomn-m Anyway this shouldn't be a string. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm it do return the body text in console.log

Comment: What about `var_dump` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mistakes that you have made are:

- mis-spelled `form` tag
- wrong passing of `data` through `ajax`

```js
$("#postButton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var body = $("#postBody").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'postBody': body},
    url: 'submitPost.php',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="postBody" type="text" id="postBody" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="postButton" id="postButton" value="POST" class="cg nq w-50">
</form>
```

Comment: can you check in browser network tab in console(F12) params tab, so that you can see whether the data is passing from ajax or not to php page