# Insert data using ajax, json, and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Intro**  I am doing an insert into the database using Ajax, PHP, and SQL.

**Error:** `alert(data)` says undefined:first_name.....I thought I defined using `$first_name = strtoupper($_POST['first_name'])` witin the `add.php` file.

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).on('click','#update_btn',function (){
     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'add.php',
             datatype: "json",
            data: {
                first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
                last_name: $("#last_name").val(),
                position: $("#position").val(),
                updated: $("#updated").val(),
            }, 
            success: function(data){ 
                alert(data);
                if (data=='ADD_OK') {
                  location.reload();
                } else {
                     alert('something wrong');
                }
                  }
             })
        });

<form id="form1" class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<select name="position" id="multiple-select-optgroup-default2" class="custom-select"> 
<option selected>Admin</option>
<option value="Teacher">Teacher</option required>
<option value="Staff">Staff</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="updated" value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' >
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm active" type="submit" name="save" id="update_btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Save</button>
</form>  
</script>
```

**Add.php**

```
 <?php
    $first_name = strtoupper($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = strtoupper($_POST['last_name']);
    $position = strtoupper($_POST['position']);
    $updated = $_POST['updated'];  
       $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name, position, updated) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
       $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $first_name, $last_name, $position, $updated);
       $add = $stmt->execute();

       if($add) {
          echo "ADD_OK";
       }
      ?>
```

Comment: what is problem in this?

Comment: thats what i am trying to figure out. my code seems perfect. My error says undefined index: first_name. same thing with last_name, position, and updated.

Comment: Can you add print_r($_POST) and  show the printed result in add.php

Comment: shows    array( ) ...........  looks like you are on to something though I kind of figured it was firing blank within the $first_name = strtoupper($_POST['first_name']);

Comment: i just added in my HTML form as well. slight chance the error is in there?  you can .val() an <input> value in HTML I am assuming..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723610/undefined-index-post-error-in-ajax-php    think my error might be in here?  need to do this:   var body = $("#postBody").val();   then later on data: {'postBody': body},

Comment: in your form there is no id attribute. add all the id attribute

Comment: thats weird, i added the id attributes today. must of not saved right. good chance this fixes problem thx

Comment: yep that fixed it. wow i feel really stupid. i 100% swear though i added the id attribute just like an hour ago. well people this is the correct ajax for insert for future readers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's undefined:first_name given an error because you don't give indexing in form but you use in jquery. show use HTML code like this and check.

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<select name="position" id="position" class="custom-select"> 
<option selected>Admin</option>
<option value="Teacher">Teacher</option required>
<option value="Staff">Staff</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="updated" id="updated" value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>' >
```

and debug with your jquery code.

Comment: correct. i have noticed when you capitalize DataType (which makes ajax JSON, the code does not fully work).

Answer (score 2):

Here is your piece of code of jQuery:

```
data: {
                first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
                last_name: $("#last_name").val(),
                position: $("#position").val(),
                updated: $("#updated").val(),
            },
```

In this you are trying to get value via id of textbox as you mentioned

> $("#first_name").val()

Change your code to this :

```
data: {
                first_name: $('input[name="first_name"]').val(),
                last_name: $('input[name="last_name"]').val(),
                position: $('input[name="position"]').val(),
                updated: $('input[name="updated"]').val(),
            },
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: dont think this works or is the typical way of doing this: http://programmerblog.net/jquery-ajax-get-example-php-mysql/